# Analysis of algorithm complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Lets assume that we have a for-loop that does n repetitions and in its body has a function that runs in Theta(n) time. Then the total complexity is Theta(n^2)?

Comment: Please add an example, so it would be clear that the two n's refer to the same thing.

Comment: from what i can understand, **yes** it will have time complexity of `O(n^2)`